# Dns registration validity

Tags: domain-name-system

I am wondering if my dns config is good, i'm beginner in these.

Alse, how can i check syntax and effect before sending modification to gandi ?

```
* 300 IN A 168.63.121.119
imap 10800 IN CNAME access.mail.gandi.net.
mc-git 10800 IN CNAME webredir.vip.gandi.net.
mc-tickets-crea 10800 IN CNAME webredir.vip.gandi.net.
mc-tickets-dev 10800 IN CNAME webredir.vip.gandi.net.
mc-wiki 10800 IN CNAME webredir.vip.gandi.net.
pop 10800 IN CNAME access.mail.gandi.net.
smtp 10800 IN CNAME relay.mail.gandi.net.
webmail 10800 IN CNAME agent.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN MX 20 fb.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN MX 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is supposed to be a DNS zone file, it is full of errors.

If you have installed bind9, you can add the DNS to a master zone file, and check them before restarting bind9. However this is not needed if you are not hosting a DNS server yourself.